# Problems installing RStudio in anaconda environment (base) on ubuntu

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio

I am not able to get rstudio into my anaconda base environment. I have tried installing it from the GUI and from the command line. In the GUI it just says that it is installing and either A) crashes, or B) stays on the installing screen forever.

I am using the following code in the base env.

```
conda install rstudio
```

System: Ubuntu 19.10 on vitualboxVM with a mac os mojave host.

Also, It is trying to install pypq, is this the problem? This doesn't seem like a package I need for my R scripts, do popular R packages depend on it? If not, can I tell anaconda just to skip installing it?

The terminal log is very long so I attached the image instead of copying the code:

[image]

UPDATE: I can install in another env, but not base.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's it. For some reason you cannot install R Studio in the base environment but you're obliged to create a specific R environment to install it.